# React Js SetState using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 React Classes:

```
const PostList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            status: "loading",
            posts: []
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div id="container">
            <ReactRouter.Link to="upload"></ReactRouter.Link>
            <a href="#/upload">{this.state.status}</a>
                {
                    this.state.posts.map(function (post) {
                        return (
                            <Post post={post} />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
});

const Upload = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="upload">Upload</div>
        );
    }
})

const MainContent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div id="inner-content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
})

const routes = (
    <Route path="/" component={MainContent}>
        <ReactRouter.IndexRoute component={PostList} />
        <Route path="upload" component={Upload} />
    </Route>
)

var render = ReactDOM.render(<Router history={History}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById("content"));
```

The question is how can i access the setState function on PostList to render new posts?

Posts will be refreshed through socket.io conenction so when a new posts arrives, i just want to set the state of the PostList to rerender the full html code with he new post(s)

Sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 1):

Add `componentDidMount` function and set up a socket listener inside it such that when a new message arrives, add it to the current list of posts

```
const PostList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            status: "loading",
            posts: []
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var that = this;
        // Be sure to set up data fetching code here

        // Set up listener for posts updates here
        socket.on('update', function (data) {
            // Assuming data contains the post content
            that.setState({
                posts: that.state.posts.concat(data)
            });
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <div id="container">
            <ReactRouter.Link to="upload"></ReactRouter.Link>
            <a href="#/upload">{this.state.status}</a>
                {
                    this.state.posts.map(function (post) {
                        return (
                            <Post post={post} />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Its working now, thank you!

But after i navigate to upload and back to main page (no refresh) (to display post list) why the postlist did not recognize my posts? So when i naviggate back without refresing the page the posts is empty again...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Mind accepting my answer if it has helped you? (:

Because when you navigate away from that page, the component is unmounted, the rendered DOM elements will be removed and replaced with your upload page. When you return back to the page, there will be no data. Hence you will need to implement a data fetching call at the start of `componentDidMount()` to fetch existing data. the `socket.on('update')` method will only tell your component that there is new post; it does not fetch existing posts.

Comment: @MSzucs I have updated my answer to show you where to set up the data fetching code.